# Python regex always match but exclude trailing optional group

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse some scraped French vocabulary using regex so I can export the data to a csv file.

### The goal

For example, when scraped, I get a string that looks like `le Zimbabwe (m)`.

Ideally, I want to separate this into three capture groups: article, word, and gender. The example would be split into `le`, `Zimbabwe`, and `m`, respectively.

However, the string sometimes does not include the gender, and would look something like `le Zimbabwe`. In this case, I'd like the third capture group to be an empty string.

### What I've tried

The closest I've gotten is the following regex:

```
^(l(?:'|es?|a))?\s?(.*)(?:\s\(([mf])\))?
```

Explanation:

- `^(l(?:'|es?|a))?\s?` finds the article, which can be any of `l'`, `le` , `la` , or `les` .
- `(.*)` is meant to capture the word (everything between the article and the gender)
- `(?:\s\(([mf])\))?` is meant to pull the `m` or `f` out from the gender if it's even there.

I'm able to get the article successfully - however, the `(.*)` capture group is gobbling the remainder of the string up, and I'm left with `le`, `Zimbabwe (m)`,  . This is desired for cases without a gender but not for cases with a gender.

I've tried looking into and using lookarounds, but I don't have too strong of a grip on regex and I'm not even sure they're what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(l(?:'|es?|a))?\s*(.*?)(?:\s*\(([mf])\))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xrgxtz/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(l(?:'|es?|a))?` - an optional capturing group #1 matching `l'`, `le`, `les` or `la`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group #2: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s*\(([mf])\))?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\s*` -  0+ whitespaces
  - `\(` - `(` char
  - `([mf])` - Group 3: `m` or `f`
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of string.